# JS/TS extending classes by passing in instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to do something as follows:  Rather than call `super` on the properties of the base class, just pass in an instance of the base class?  I am getting an error in my editor when trying but wondering if I am missing something if it's just not allowed.  Do I really have to pass in each property of the extended class if I already have an instance of the base class?

```
class Person {
  private name: string
  private age: number
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}


class Employee extends Person {
  private position: string;
  //pass in the instance of Person already created
  constructor(person: Person, position: string) {
    super(person);
    this.position = position;
  } 
}
```

---

```
let philInstance = new Person("Phil", 20);
let janitor = new Employee(philInstance, "janitor")
```

Comment: Well, you *shouldn't* pass a whole instance as arguments; rather you'd use `const janitor = new Employee('Phil', 20, 'janitor')` - where `janitor instanceof Person`, you don't need a separate `philInstance` (who is not an employee). Or you shouldn't use inheritance, and define a `Role` class that consists of a person and their position (which also makes it easy for one person to be part of different roles).

Comment: Either you should make the constructor take each property separately or all at once, and subclasses need to be consistent with superclasses this way.  Or you do a [combination of both](https://tsplay.dev/wRlxvm), but that's yucky.  And private properties just makes this worse; what's the point of having `name` and `age` be `private` if you're subclassing it?  Then the subclass has no access to those properties... is that what you really want?  Why not `protected` or even `public`?